# É possível usar chave composta para Entity Framework com Model First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, code-first

Tenho a modelagem a baixo e vou precisar mapear chaves compostas como o embedded id do hibernate, mas no entity framework usando o model first, é possível ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você temtou criar o banco, depois fazer o import para o seu projeto (para criar as Models)? se sim, vc tentou modificar as model para especificar para o entity as chavers compostas?

Answer (score -3):

Sim, da seguinte forma

```
public class ActivityType
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A ActivityName is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Activity Name must not exceed 50 characters")]
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }

}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466374/composite-key-with-ef-4-1-code-first

Comment: Mas essa solução é para code first e não model first.

Comment: Você deve ter se expressado de maneira equivocada. No Entity, há as opção Empty Code First Model e Code First from **database**. Code first e model first, no caso, é a mesma coisa! MSDN Model first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Vou dar o exemplo para a tabela Preco_congelado. Na classe de contexto que possui as configurações do EF configure da seguinte forma:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Preco_congelado>()
            .ToTable("Preco_congelado")
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.Id_MateriaPrima, p.Id_Fornecedor }).IsUnique(true);
```